# How to configure cookieless domain for a 2nd level subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, cookies, dns, subdomain

I am trying to fix GTMetrix "Use cookie-free domains" error on my site shop.sin.org.pl. My issue might be related to the fact I do not use WWW nor a main level domain, but a 2nd level subdomain. All the examples I found online apply to top domains or sites with www. Perhaps this is why they didn't work? Is it possible to achieve cookie-free domain for a low level subdomain without using a completely different domain, not just another subdomain?

1. I want to set a cookiefree domain "static.sin.org.pl" to serve static content to my main site "shop.sin.org.pl".
2. I set up a new page "static.sin.org.pl" with symlink to my main page:

```
    ln -s ~/domains/shop.sin.org.pl/public_html/wp-content/ public_html
```

3. I set up CNAME for "static.sin.org.pl" to point to "shop.sin.org.pl"
4. I changed my main site "shop.sin.org.pl" wp-config to include the following:

```
  define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "https://static.sin.org.pl"); 
  define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "shop.sin.org.pl");
```

1. I even changed .htaccess to include:

```
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|json)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
```

6. Finally I edited my database with the following command:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'shop.sin.org.pl/wp-content/','static.sin.org.pl/')
```

7. Finally I cleaned server cache, wordpress cache and Cloudflare cache, only to find the same error still show up on GTMetrix. The site did not break though, so I'm not sure why the error would persist. Did my changes apply or not? What am I missing?
8. (FYI I have reverted the database change for now)

[image]

Thank you in advice for taking the time to help out.